# bash script failure to mount disk

Tags: linux, bash, system, drive

I have 2 scripts, `script.sh`:

```
./mount.sh
```

and, `mount.sh`:

```
mount /dev/sdb4 /mnt/mountpoint
```

`script.sh` does some steps and invokes `mount.sh` which mounts the disk that is `sdb`. The `mount.sh` script works fine, but, when invoked from the `scripts.sh` script it fails to mount. I do not have the error messages, if any, from invoking `mount.sh` from `scripts.sh`. But, what possible reason could there be for that to fail?

Comment: There is no reason for it to fail.  The bits first script that you don't show might do something wrong. Also an error message would be _exceedingly_ good to see.

Comment: Show us the output of `sh -x script.sh`  and `sh -x mount.sh`. So far your description is not much different from *Doctor, it hurts*.

Answer (score 1):

We may only guess but experience suggests it's always about PATH or permissions.

Probably, while "script.sh does some steps" it also changes current directory, so `./mount.sh` simply fails to invoke. Review "script.sh" to prevent this.